# How do I get my Body to be all black? Some of it is Grey?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://gx0st.com

So, if you guys check that, at least on my resolution 1920x1080. It has grey at the bottom, so it isn't fitting all the way. And if you check https://gx0st.com/contact.html you will see the same. If you guys could please help a noobie, I'd appreciate it. I just want it to be all black, and fit.

If you guys have any recommendations too on how to optimize it for mobile, that'd be fun. I will look into that anywho. But thanks to anyone who helps me with the first problem. <3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div id="page-wrapper">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="logo">
      </div>

     <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSM3fpzXloGLNL7N6qnjamA" href="Youtube"><b>Youtube</b></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://gx0st.com/contact.html" href="Contact"><b>Contact</b></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container"></div>

    <section id="hero">
      <form id="form"
            action="mailto:godislove1427@gmail.com">
        <input 
               name="email"
               id="email"
               type="email"
               placeholder="Email Address"
               required/>

        <input id="submit" type="submit"
               value="HQ" class="btn" /></input></form>
    </section>


      </section>
      <section id="how-it-works">
        <iframe 
                id="video"
                height="315"
                src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/mjq6kZSwTmI"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen></iframe></section>
      <section id="pricing">
        <div class="product" id="tenor">

          <ul>






        </div>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <span>Copyright 2018, Ghost Robles</span>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>

<style>
@font-face {font-family: 'vcr_osd_mono-webfont'; src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot'); src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('webfont.svg#svgFontname') format('svg');}



  title {text-align: center;
  font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";}

h2 {text-align: center;
font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";}

p {text-align: center;
color: purple;
font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";}

nav {text-align: center;}

body {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/toons/too-3/too297.cur), auto;}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: rgb(255, 2, 2);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";

}

/** global classes styling **/

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 3px rgb(255, 0, 0) solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 75px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  header {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 60vw;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
}

.logo > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .logo > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

nav {
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
  nav li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

nav > ul {
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  nav > ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

#hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#hero > h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#hero input[type="email"] {
  max-width: 275px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#hero input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #c300ffea;
}



@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #hero {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}

#features {
  margin-top: 30px;
}


@media (max-width: 550px) {
  #features .icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

#features .desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 125px;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  #features .desc {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #features {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

#how-it-works {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#how-it-works > iframe {
  max-width: 560px;
  width: 100%;
}

#pricing {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}



.product > .level {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.product > h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.product > ol {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.product > ol > li {
  padding: 5px 0;
}


.product > button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #pricing {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .product {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 20px;
}

footer > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer > ul > li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

footer > span {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

::placeholder {text-align: center;}

.btn {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
</style>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-137617043-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-137617043-2');
</script>
</html>


**Contact.HTML**
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link
  rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"
<!-- START NAV -->

<nav id="navbar" class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">HQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- END NAV -->
<!-- START CONTACT SECTION -->
<body>
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
  <div class="contact-section-header">
    <h2>Let's work together!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-links">
    <a
      href="https://www.instagram.com/ghostrobles"
      target="_blank"
      class="btn contact-details"
      ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</a
    >
    <a
      id="profile-link"
      href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSM3fpzXloGLNL7N6qnjamA"
      target="_blank"
      class="btn contact-details"
      ><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> Youtube</a
    >
    <a
    >
    <a href="mailto:godislove1427@gmail.com" class="btn contact-details"
      ><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Gmail</a
    >
  </div>
</section>

</body>

<!-- END CONTACT SECTION -->

<!-- START FOOTER SECTION -->

<footer class="site-footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSM3fpzXloGLNL7N6qnjamA"
    &copy;Ghost Robles>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSM3fpzXloGLNL7N6qnjamA" target="_blank"
      >&copy;Ghost Robles
    </a>
  </p>


<!-- END FOOTER SECTION -->
</footer>

<style>
    @font-face {font-family: 'vcr_osd_mono-webfont'; src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot'); src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('webfont.svg#svgFontname') format('svg');}
    /* Custom properties/variables  */

:root {
  --main-white: #ff0000;
  --main-red: #000000;
  --main-blue: #000000;
  --main-gray: #000000;
}

/* Base reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* box-sizing and font sizing */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* Set font size for easy rem calculations
   * default document font size = 16px, 1rem = 16px, 100% = 16px
   * (100% / 16px) * 10 = 62.5%, 1rem = 10px, 62.5% = 10px
  */
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* A few media query to set some font sizes at different screen sizes.
 * This helps automate a bit of responsiveness.
 * The trick is to use the rem unit for size values, margin and padding.
 * Because rem is relative to the document font size
 * when we scale up or down the font size on the document
 * it will affect all properties using rem units for the values.
*/

/* I am using the em unit for breakpoints
 * The calculation is the following
 * screen size divided by browser base font size
 * As an example: a breakpoint at 980px
 * 980px / 16px = 61.25em
*/

/* 1200px / 16px = 75em */
@media (max-width: 75em) {
  html {
    font-size: 60%;
  }
}

/* 980px / 16px = 61.25em */
@media (max-width: 61.25em) {
  html {
    font-size: 58%;
  }
}

/* 460px / 16px = 28.75em */
@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  html {
    font-size: 55%;
  }
}

/* Base styles */

body {
  font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";
  font-size: 1.8rem; /* 18px */
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: rgb(108, 6, 204);

}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4.2rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--main-white);
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* nav */

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--main-red);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .nav {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-list {
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  background: var(--main-blue);
}

/* Welcome section */

.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #3a3d40 0%, #181719 100%);
}

.welcome-section > p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
  color: var(--main-red);
}

/* Projects section */

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10rem 2rem;
  background: var(--main-blue);
}

.projects-section-header {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto 6rem auto;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid var(--main-white);
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .projects-section-header {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

/* "Automagic" image grid using no media queries */
.projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 30.625em) {
  .projects-section {
    padding: 6rem 1rem;
  }

  .projects-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.project {
  background: var(--main-gray);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.code {
  color: var(--main-gray);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.project:hover .code {
  color: #ff7f50;
}

.project-image {
  height: calc(100% - 6.8rem);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.project-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-show-all {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: var(--main-gray);
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.btn-show-all:hover {
  background: var(--main-red);
}

.btn-show-all:hover > i {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

.btn-show-all > i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

/* Contact section */

.contact-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  background: var(--main-gray);
}

.contact-section-header > h2 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .contact-section-header > h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

.contact-section-header > p {
  font-style: italic;
}

.contact-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contact-details {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #000000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.contact-details:hover {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: default;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: var(--main-gray);
  border-top: 4px solid var(--main-red);

}

footer > p {
  margin: 2rem;
}

footer i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.site-footer {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#footer-content {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
</style>
```

Comment: That title made me giggle :)

Comment: Lol.....I died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the black fill all the page, just type at the css:

```
html, body{
   height: 100vh;
}

body{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

And change the z-index of the nav to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide a background color to the body element

```
body{
   background-color: black;
}
```

This color should persist through window resizing as well

Answer (score 0):

I think that just setting the body height to 100% will fix it.
CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that the content you've added and the way you style it does not fill the entire screen, therefore the color ends where your 'last element' is placed.

setting `height: 100vh` will make the height of the element the same as the height of the screen itself. Avoid setting heights in the body, your webpage might grow and that will become a problem.